# Sonata admin update bundle error

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

After updating sonata-admin from 2.x to 3.x i get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Sonata\FormatterBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CKEditorCompilerPass' not found in /vagrant/src/vendor/sonata-project/formatter-bundle/SonataFormatterBundle.php on line 28
```

My sonata composer

```
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "2.0.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "~1",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "^3.0",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "~2.1",
    "sonata-project/page-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/news-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "~1",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3.0"
```

Maybe have ideas why?
Also. i'm using php7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CKEditorCompilerPass` was removed in 3.0.1.

I suggest you require at least the formatter-bundle as:

```
composer require sonata/formatter-bundle ^3.0.1
```

Comment: Let my try your suggestion